# Let the user change the width of a NSTableView

Tags: swift, macos

I'm trying to implement a Mail.app-like behavior for my Master-Detail View Controller. How can I allow the user to change the tableview-size?[image]

Comment: This is an enclosing `NSSplitView` with appropriate Autolayout constraints.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just had to use a `NSSplitView`, thanks to vadian.